# ASP.NET MVC EF Request.Form peligroso

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seguridad

Hola amigos oigan quiero hacer un insert y obtengo el siguiente error

> Se detectó un posible valor Request.Form peligroso en el cliente
>   (texto="...adores de

Entiendo que esta es una medida de seguridad para evitar ataques por `script`, la cuestión es que necesito un `insert` dentro de mi base de datos texto con html, ese `<b>` es de una etiqueta de negritas. Y así una serie de elementos html, alguien sabe como puedo evitarlo?

Este es mi código

```js
  var myText = $('.Editor-editor');
  var strData = myText.html();
  var icono = 'manzana'


function InsertBeneficio(strData, icono) {
  //console.log(data)
  document.getElementById('modal-header').innerHTML = 'Agregar Beneficio';
  document.getElementById('modal-body').innerHTML = `
            <div align="center">

                    <h3>Ingresar Beneficio</h3>
                    <form action="/DashboardAdmin/InsertBeneficios" method="post">

                        <input type="text" name="texto" class="hidden" value="` + strData + `" />
                        <input type="text" name="icono" class="hidden" value="` + icono + `" />
                        <input type="text" class="hidden" name="id_userCreated" value="@User.Identity.GetUserId()" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="name" value="Insertar" />
                    </form>

                    <br/>
                    <a href="/DashboardAdmin/">Volver a panel</a>
              </div>`;

  $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
```

Y este mi método

```
  [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertBeneficios(string id_userCreated, string texto, string icono)
    {

        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {

            var contacto = new HomeBeneficios()
            {
               texto =  texto,
               icono = icono

            };
            db.HomeBeneficios.Add(contacto);
            //db..add(cat);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        var action = "Insert";
        var comments = "Beneficios ingresado por el usuario : ";
        InsertInBitacora(id_userCreated, action, comments + id_userCreated);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Se detectó un posible valor
>   Request.Form peligroso en el cliente (texto="...adores de
>   valores de..."). Descripción: ASP.NET ha detectado datos en
>   la solicitud que son potencialmente peligrosos porque incluyen script
>   o marcado HTML. Es posible que los datos representen un intento de
>   poner en peligro la seguridad de la aplicación, como un ataque XSS. Si
>   el tipo de entrada es apropiado en la aplicación, puede incluir código
>   en una página web para permitirlo explícitamente. Para obtener más
>   información, consulte http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.
>        Detalles de la excepción: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: Se detectó un posible valor
>   Request.Form peligroso en el cliente (texto="...adores de 
>   Metas...").

Error de código fuente:

> Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la
>   solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de
>   la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del
>   seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Seguimiento de la pila:

> [HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): Se detectó un posible
>   valor Request.Form peligroso en el cliente (texto="...adores de 
>   Metas...").]
>          System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +9926025
>          System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass280_0.b__0(String
>   key, String value) +23
>          System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key) +9924087
>          System.Web.HttpValueCollection.GetValues(String name) +18
>          System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResultPlaceholder.GetResultFromCollection(String
>   key, NameValueCollection collection, CultureInfo culture) +20
>          System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider.GetValue(String key, Boolean skipValidation) +106
>          System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderCollection.GetValue(String key, Boolean skipValidation) +89
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +267
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +335
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__0(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +346
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +20
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +105
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: Indica por favor, el código de la Vista donde realizas el submit, y el código del Controlador donde recibes el request peligroso.

Comment: Lo recomendable es que puedas crear el insert, en lugar de leerlo directamente desde el código HTML.

Comment: También el texto del error completo. Gracias.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el HTML que genera al ejecutar "InsertarBeneficio", quiero ver qué hay en `document.getElementById('modal-body').innerHTML`

Comment: @fredyfx es el form que está justo que estoy pasando en el primer recuadro de código, es un form simple

Comment: No me estoy dejando entender, veamos, una vez que le hayas dado a ejecutar "InsertarBeneficio", dale click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y mira el HTML que ha generado, ese HTML agrégalo a la pregunta. Tengo cierta sospecha que la concatenación de los valores cuando defines "value" están generando ese problema

Comment: @fredyfx hola mi Fred como siempre tu intelecto me seduce y me soprende, efectivamente si mando texto sin  **< >** me captura y me hace todo el insert, ¿ qué puedo hacer este caso? Necesito guardar todo ese contenido con y sin html

Comment: Eso sonó muy raro o.o, revisa la respuesta, creo que es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Donde defines el elemento con la clase (class) `.Editor-editor?`. Ya que ese es el elemento que estás almacenando en el input `texto=` que te da el error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás enviando al servidor **código Html** (en tu caso **< >** según indicas en los comentarios), por defecto la Acción de tu Controlador lo interpretará como **código peligroso** y lanzará una excepción.

Para solucionar este problema, y si **no es importante la seguridad** de los datos recibidos en el Controlador, puedes anular este comportamiento añadiendo a tu Acción el atributo `[ValidateInput(false)]`.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult InsertBeneficios(string id_userCreated, string texto, string icono)
{
    using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
    {
        var contacto = new HomeBeneficios()
        {
           texto =  texto,
           icono = icono
        };
        db.HomeBeneficios.Add(contacto);
        //db..add(cat);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    var action = "Insert";
    var comments = "Beneficios ingresado por el usuario : ";
    InsertInBitacora(id_userCreated, action, comments + id_userCreated);
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero, almacena en la base de datos, RAW HTML, es decir, HTML puro, sin codificar ni saneamientos (sanitizings).

Según la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

En tu modelo:

```
[AllowHtml] //Agrega este Data-Annotation.
public string PropiedadQueTieneHTML{ get; set; }
```

Eso sí, al momento de mostrar (renderizar) la información, SÍ o SÍ el HTML debe ser "saneado", para ello utiliza la librería: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/ Con esto te evitas problemas de ataques XSS.

```
@Html.Raw(HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml(Model.PropiedadQueTieneHTML))
```

Lo interesante de la librería: puedes ver el código fuente en https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Y ver parte de su funcionamiento en: http://xss.ganss.org/

Otro detalle adicional, todo desarrollador web tiene el deber de revisar https://www.owasp.org para que entienda cómo mejorar la seguridad de sus aplicaciones web.

Comment: oye fred solo una cosa, como le hago para poder mandar por input todos mis datos? o es mejor mandarlos por ajax?

Comment: Da lo mismo si los envías por Ajax o por un submit tradicional, lo que acabo de recordar es que olvidé mencionar agregar el `[ValidateInput(false)]` en la acción del controlador que usas